# QGIS : mbtiles data (GeoServer) does not display

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wms, mbtiles

I succeed in GeoServer (2.18.1) to set a new mbtiles file. I can see the preview data (OpenLayers view) in GeoServer.
Then I try to display the data throw QGIS (WMS). But the data does not display in the canvas.

In the QGIS log I have an error message:

```
2021-07-27T17:39:10     WARNING    Erreur de requête de carte (Réponse : Error transferring https://sig-geo-prd.andra.fr/geoserver/gwc/service/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=4.21875,47.8125,5.624999999999987566,49.21875&SRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=4&HEIGHT=4&LAYERS=test%3AIGN_PLAN_V2&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/png&DPI=96&MAP_RESOLUTION=96&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi:96&TRANSPARENT=TRUE - server replied: ; URL : https://sig-geo-prd.andra.fr/geoserver/gwc/service/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=4.21875,47.8125,5.624999999999987566,49.21875&SRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=4&HEIGHT=4&LAYERS=test%3AIGN_PLAN_V2&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/png&DPI=96&MAP_RESOLUTION=96&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi:96&TRANSPARENT=TRUE)
```

In geoserver, i have the following logs :

```
2021-07-27 18:39:31,831 ERROR [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - Request failed
org.geowebcache.grid.TileDimensionsMismatchException: The requested tile dimensions 4x4 do not match those of the grid set (256x256)
```

Comment: Can you share your mbtiles file?

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems clear enough:

`The requested tile dimensions 4x4 do not match those of the grid set (256x256)`

You need to use a tile size that matches the gridset in this case 256x256. So your request becomes:

```
https://sig-geo-prd.andra.fr/geoserver/gwc/service/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=4.21875,47.8125,5.624999999999987566,49.21875&SRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&LAYERS=test%3AIGN_PLAN_V2&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/png&DPI=96&MAP_RESOLUTION=96&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi:96&TRANSPARENT=TRUE
```